# Yii preventing Apple Push Notification script from running

Tags: yii, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a script which does an Apple push notification to an App. The script is:

```
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is the alert text', 
                         'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default',
             'article_id'=> '110'   
            );
$payload = json_encode($payload);


$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = '/var/www/schoolspace/apple_server/mountmercy/MountMercy-dev.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$deviceToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);


$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
```

I have created the required .pem. When I run this as a standalone script with:

```
php index.php
```

everything works and the app receives the notification. There is a warning however:

```
Warning: socket_close(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource
```

But it still works. However, when I run this in Yii, I get the error:

```
stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: Unable to set private key file `/var/www/schoolspace/apple_server/mountmercy/MountMercy-dev.pem'
```

I get this error even when setting YII_DEBUG to false. I run this segment of code in the my Yii "Message" model in afterSave(). It's EXACTLY the same as the standalone script. But somehow Yii is preventing it from running. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are receiving the notification that means your `pem` file might be okay, but
your code doesn't show where you are providing the `passphrase`. You can try the below code which worked for me.

```
            $badge = 1;
            $sound = 'default';
            $development = false;//change it to true if in development
            $passphrase='passphrase';//pass phrase of the pem file

            $payload = array();
            $payload['aps'] = array('alert' => $msg_text, 'badge' => intval($badge), 'sound' => $sound);
            $payload = json_encode($payload);

            $apns_url = NULL;
            $apns_cert = NULL;
            $apns_port = 2195;

            if($development)
            {
                $apns_url = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
                $apns_cert = dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile).'/file.pem';
            }
            else
            {
                $apns_url = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
                $apns_cert = dirname(Yii::app()->request->scriptFile).'/file.pem';
            }
            $stream_context = stream_context_create();
            stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apns_cert);
            stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

            $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apns_url . ':' . $apns_port, $error, $error_string, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);            
            $device_tokens2= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

            $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', $device_tokens2 ) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
            $msg=fwrite($apns, $apns_message);
            @socket_close($apns);
            @fclose($apns);
```